# Riley Riddles go round and round

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is an animal, my suffix is round,
>
> My infix hears your screaming sound.
>
> I make you move, i lead your way
>
> Tell me who i am, right away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> bearing

My prefix is an animal

> bear

my suffix is round,

> ring

My infix hears your screaming sound.

> ear

I make you move, i lead your way

> A bearing is both a mechanical element that helps wheels move, as well as the direction of one's movement.